# How to replace the first 8 characters of a file in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using regex in notepad++ and I need to replace only the first 8 characters of each file, not from each line, just the first 8 characters in the first line. I need this:

Now:

```
40932182ErikG
asdadasdada
rewqrasdasdasdas
```

I need this:

```
0       ErikG
asdadasdada
rewqrasdasdasdas
```

I found that this "^.{0,8}" let me replace the first 8 characters of each line but I only need to replace from the first line.

Thank you!

Comment: If you cannot implement my solution, please add a screenshot to the question, or just share a link to it showing what you are really doing.

Comment: Please add the screenshot of your S&R settings, what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

**Find What**: `^.{0,8}((?s:.*))`
**Replace With**: `0    $1`

The point is to match the first 0 to 8 chars, and then capture the rest of the file into a group to restore it later with the `$1` placeholder.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of the line
- `.{0,8}` - 0 to 8 chars other than line break chars
- `((?s:.*))` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars, up to the end of the file (greedy match, `?s:` enables the DOTALL modifier, `.` matches newlines, too, now).

[image]

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer, it didn't work. It selects all the characters in the file, and don't replace anything.

Comment: @ErikGomez You did not use it correctly. It will match all characters, but the first 0 to 8 chars will get matched only, and the rest will be captured.Use it exactly as I suggest, and it will work, because it is the solution. I added the screenshot as a **proof it works**.